# Is there any PHP SMTP Protocol Class with Attachements

Tags: php

I tried this but no attachment option.

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/14-PHP-Sends-e-mail-messages-via-SMTP-protocol.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php#attachment).

Answer (score 5):

There are several widely used options for sending email yourself (if you must):

- [Swiftmailer](http://www.swiftmailer.org)
- [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)
- [Zend Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html)

They all handle attachments for you. Generally, avoid PHPClasses.org.

Comment: +1 for SwiftMailer excellent mailing wrapper. You can also try Zend_Mail

Comment: oi, forgot zend mail, adding it now :)